# How to Measure Code Coverage Rspec-Puppet

Tags: tdd, code-coverage, puppet

I would like to Measure Code Coverage Rspec-puppet by implementing the following [example](http://www.morethanseven.net/2014/01/25/code-coverage-for-puppet-modules/).

I have added `at_exit { RSpec::Puppet::Coverage.report! }` to the end of the `./spec/classes/init_spec.rb` file.

**init_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "vim" do
  let(:facts) { { :operatingsystem => 'Ubuntu' } }

  it { should contain_class('vim::ubuntu')}

end

at_exit { RSpec::Puppet::Coverage.report! }
```

Running `rspec` results in:

`/etc/puppet/modules/vim/spec/classes/init_spec.rb:12: uninitialized constant RSpec::Puppet::Coverage (NameError)`

`rake spec` results in:

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- ace
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:357:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:357:in `standard_rake_options'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1298:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1298:in `parse_in_order'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1254:in `catch'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1254:in `parse_in_order'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1248:in `order!'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1339:in `permute!'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1360:in `parse!'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:425:in `handle_options'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:74:in `init'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:72:in `init'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:64:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/bin/rake:27
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Puppet Labs' [github fork](https://github.com/puppetlabs/rspec-puppet) of `rspec-puppet` is outdated by more than a year. The coverage code is currently only found in the author's [original repo](https://github.com/rodjek/rspec-puppet).

Just pulling `master` from that repo might be enough to resolve your issue.

Comment: I have tried to install rspec-puppet using `gem install rspec-puppet` and by pulling the master, but the error persists

Comment: `sudo gem specific_install -l https://github.com/rodjek/rspec-puppet.git` results in `git installing from https://github.com/rodjek/rspec-puppet.git
Cloning into '/tmp/d20140417-14412-w3gr9'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 1846, done.
remote: Total 1846 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (1846/1846), 311.40 KiB | 174 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (766/766), done.
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `build' for Gem::Package:Module`

Comment: So...your installation didn't work at all? Have you tried just cloning the repo to any location and adding its `lib/` directory to the ruby library search path?

Comment: I have cloned the repo to /tmp using `sudo git clone https://github.com/rodjek/rspec-puppet.git`, installed rubygems (`sudo apt-get install rubygems`), built the gem (`sudo gem build rspec-puppet.gemspec`), installed the gem (`sudo gem install rspec-puppet-1.0.1.gem`), ran `rspec` puppet again and now it works! Thank you! I will accept and upvote the answer.
.

Finished in 0.05659 seconds
1 example, 0 failures

Total resources:   3
Touched resources: 1
Resource coverage: 33.33%

Untouched resources:

  Custom_multiple_files[line_numbers]
  Class[Vim::Ubuntu::Config]